# Como manter um servidor nodejs em execução permanente?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Quero saber como faço para manter o meu servidor [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) em execução permanente no meu [vps](/questions/tagged/vps) Ubuntu que comprei sem a necessidade de ter que executar o Putty e rodar o comando `node app.js`. Eu fiz um REST API que será consumida por uma aplicação mobile então o server deve estar sempre em execução.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode usar o [nohup](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/O-comando-nohup):

```
$ nohup node server.js > output.log &
```

Assim, poderá deslogar e o servidor continuará ativo.

---

Para rodar "pra sempre", recomendo utilizar o [Forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever).

```
$ npm install forever
$ forever start server.js
```

Para ver os servidores em execucão, utilize a opção `list`

```
$ forever list
```

O bom do Forever é que ele automaticamente restarta seu servidor caso, por algum motivo, ele morra.

Para mais detalhes, veja [este link](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/) (em inglês).

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecione o fluxo para um arquivo de log

```
node app.js > log.txt &
```

Para deixar ainda melhor, crie um serviço para iniciar a api: http://comofoiquefiz.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/como-adicionar-um-servico-no-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um cron que execute um arquivo em python que vai manter a sua aplicação sempre rodando. O bom de usar o cron é que ele vai garantir que o servidor node seja inicializado novamente.

**Exemplo do cron**

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/cron/vp.py
```

**Exemplo do arquivo vp.py**

```
import os
import commands
saida = commands.getoutput('ps -A')

# verifica se existe o node nos processos retornados por ps -A
if 'node' in saida:
        pass
        # print "Node em execucao..."
else:
        # se nao existe, entao executa o servidor node em segundo plano...
        os.system('node /usr/bin/server_chat.js &')
```

Caso você queira, é interessante colocar nesse arquivo python para gerar logs de quando o node é inicializado.